# Nesting formats in String.format

Tags: java, string-formatting

Is nesting formats possible with java's `String.format`? An example would be;

```
String fooPadded = String.format("FOO:%1$10s", "foo");

// fooPadded:"FOO:       foo"

String barPadded = String.format("%1$15s", fooPadded);

// barPadded:" FOO:       foo"
```

Instead of calling 2 consecutive `format` methods which would be expensive in terms of performance, I want to wrap *foo* rule with *bar* rule in other terms reduce format to single one.

Comment: Why do you think having a single format String would improve performance?

Comment: No, formatting is not expensive performance-wise.

Answer (score 0):

Are you having a performance problem in your program? If so, you are right in wanting to do something about it. If not, you shouldn’t. If you have, `String.format()` would not be my first suspect nor the second for taking too long time. Go measure before making any changes to your nice and readable code.

That said, I think the way to limit to one call to `format()` is:

```
    String barPadded = String.format("%5s%10s", "FOO:", "foo");
```

I don’t think you can do nesting except with two calls as in your question.

And if `"foo"` happened to be exactly 11 chars long, my code would not give the exact same result as the code in your question.